# Spring - config apache commons email

Tags: java, spring, email, apache-commons

I want to use HtmlEmail in apache commons-email in a spring app, so i use the config xml as following:

```
<bean id="commonsEmail" class="org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail">
    <property name="hostName" value="smtp.example.com" />
    <property name="TLS" value="true"/>
    <property name="smtpPort" value="587"/>
</bean>
```

But i can't initialize it because of the smtpPort property:

Invalid property 'smtpPort' of bean class [org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail]: Bean property 'smtpPort' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Please tell me what i've done wrong ? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because the `smtpPort` property is ambiguous - the `getSmtpPort` method returns a `String`, but the `setSmtpPort` method takes an `int`. Spring gets cold feet at this point, and throws the exception saying that the bean property is invalid.

I think both `HtmlEmail` and Spring are at fault here - `HtmlEmail` for bad API design, Spring for being unnecessarily pedantic.

The solution I'd recommend is one of:

1. Create your own subclass of `HtmlEmail`, defining a new setter method, with a new name,  which delegates to `setSmtpPort`. This is quick and easy, but is rather poor design in itself.
2. [Write an implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) of Spring's `FactoryBean` interface, which gets the job of instantiating and configuring an `HtmlEmail` instance. This is more work than (1), but is a cleaner design.
3. Ditch Commons Email completely, and use [Spring's own Email abstraction layer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html). This would be my recommended option.